# I can't set up JDK on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I saw this,

[image: Java runtime could not be located]

and clicked on it. It redirected me to the Red Hat site and made me download Red Hat Developer Studio, but as I said, I want it in Visual Studio Code. I did download the JDK, but what should I do next?

Comment: This could probably help. https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/Java/hello-world/install-jdk

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: That image link is now broken: *"404 Not Found"*. Does [the original](http://prntscr.com/kzf994) still work (it seems weirdly JavaScript'y)?

Answer (score 21):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>.
- Search for *"java.home"*.

In case you are on the newest Visual Studio Code version:

Type in your Java path (*don't* forget to put the path in `" "`).

In case you are on an older version of Visual Studio Code:

- Click on the pencil next to the line starting with *"java.home"*.
- click on *"Copy to settings"*.
- Type in your Java path (*don't* forget to put the path in `" "`).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

If you don't know your Java path, type in `which java` in your terminal (on Windows, please note the right format, e.g., `"java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2"`).

Comment: hi, amirali
followed step 1,2 and 3 without problems, but clicking ctrl+'s' nothing happens
how do I finalize the changes in the workspace settings?

Comment: @FrancescoIapicca What's your operating system? Have you used vscode before? And please share what `where java` returns with us.

Comment: I'm on win10, I use vscode for dart and flutter, but I have to import an .aar file
and call the service using java(hopefully kotlin), so yes (I use it) and no (never with java) [edit:

{"java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2"
}

Comment: @FrancescoIapicca Have you added `"java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2"` to your `settings.json` file? please make sure you have written it in correct format.

Comment: java.home is deprecated now. use java.jdt.ls.java.home

Answer (score 3):

Shifting to Java 11 did the trick for me. That is the minimum version required to run the **Language Support for Java** extension.
After installation, open your `settings.json` file with the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl or CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type "settings"
- Click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

Then add this line:

```
"java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Don't forget a trailing comma if you add this setting before another.

Comment: The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64) does not point to a JDK.