# How can I create a Maven Project using VS Code when java.home is not working

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a maven project in VS code and cannot because the JAVA_HOME is not set. I tried many options all have failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baq6T.png)

I went into the control panel menu to create environmental variables. JAVA_HOME and PATH are both set to where my JDK is. I also tried to edit the settings.json with code to get it to read the path, and by trying to create JAVA_HOME.

I tried this code earlier and removed it because it did nothing.
"java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
"maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true

I also adjusted it because they added stuff infront of java.home I forget exactly but something like
java.jdt.ls.java.home

After trying many attempts nothing worked. So I figured I have to make my own post because reading related posts get me nowhere.

I checked out these among other sites.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven
[Cannot set java.home in VS Code Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372849/cannot-set-java-home-in-vs-code-maven-project)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGi1.png)

Comment: Did you close the VS Code entirely and open it again after you set the JAVA_HOME into your machine's environment variable?

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. It now says the file directory to the jdk was unexpected at this time

Comment: I got it to work. I removed the stuff in json settings and moved the variable from user to system and it worked. I think not restarting it and having two java_home made issues.